# 12-04 lts auto update is "broken" do I need to reinstall?

Tags: update-manager

auto update is "broken" and will not work. I now have a red "no entry" sign at the top of the screen. It says "error: BrokenCount >0"
I am completely lost, and what I have seen on the forum looks like its written in serbo-croat to me. Do I have to reload the Ubuntu disc
and if I do will I lose everything I have on the machine? I do not want to go back to anything with Microsoft written on it please..

Comment: I have pretty much the same issue. I have just updated to 16.04 and I too have the no entry sign at the top. I have a message that comes up saying package download failed and I cannot update them.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands from a terminal:

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get -f install`

If all of those succeed (or have nothing to do), then your broken packages should be fixed. If they don't, you'll get an error message explaining what the problem is.